# Some QLineEdit questions

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I'm using Python with PyQt and I have a few problems with my `QLineEdits`.

1. First of all, I want to put text on them, but not the regular one, I mean the transparent text that disappears when you click on the `QLineEdit`.
2. How can I disable clicking on my `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much like this:

```
linedit = QtGui.QlineEdit()
linedit.setPlaceholderText("My grey text which disappear when I click on it")
linedit.setEnabled(False)
```

with Qt minimum version 4.7 and latest PyQt 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW, is this the 2nd or 3d you answer to my questions XD